# Are there historic examples of slave emancipation leading to mass starvation?

Tags: slavery

I was reading this article about "[1 Million New Afrikan / Blacks Died From Starvation & Disease When Slavery Ended & Reconstruction Period ( Largest Biological Crisis of 19th Century)](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2160484/The-end-slavery-led-hunger-death-millions-black-Americans-Extraordinary-claims-new-book.html)" and I was wondering if this is unique to the case of the civil war in US or if it ever happened in another country? I mean where freeing slaves with one decision led to tragedy?

Comment: This seems more fit to History rather than politics. Do you have a link for further reading about this issue?

Comment: https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2160484/The-end-slavery-led-hunger-death-millions-black-Americans-Extraordinary-claims-new-book.html

Comment: This is indeed a historic question and not a political one. I moved this question to history stack exchange.

Comment: This seems less about a nation freeing slaves as such, and more about a nation's underbudget and bobbled emergency relief efforts as well as failing to protect its newly recognized citizens from politically organized crime by racists.  Big wars make big messes, and require extensive postwar cleanup or there will be famine, disease and misrule.

Comment: I believe that Haiti had that problem  - you might want to check Mike Duncan's podcast on the Haitian revolution   If I get time later I'll look up the link.

Comment: I'd be interested in what that article was based on.  The Daily Mail is not the most trustworthy publication, and the URL mentions an extraordinary new book.  Extraordinary new books are very frequently rubbish.

Answer (score 2):

I may note that in the 1850 census the number of blacks was listed as 3,233,057 and in the 1860 census it was 3,853,478, an increase of 620,241 or 19.18 %, while the number of mulattoes was 405,751 in 1850 and 588,352 in 1860, an increase of 182,601 or 45.00 %.

*Population of the United States in 1860; Compiled from the Original Returns of the Eighth Census, under the direction of the secretary of the Interior, by Joseph C. G. Kennedy* 1864.  Introduction, page x.

https://archive.org/details/populationofusin00kennrich/page/n3[1](https://archive.org/details/populationofusin00kennrich/page/n3)

And the colored population of the United states - combined blacks and mulattoes - is listed as 757,208 in 1790, 1,002,067 in 1800 (increase of 244,859 or 32.33 %), 1,377,808 in 1810 (increase of 375,741 or 37.49 %), 1,771,656 in 1820 (increase of 393,848 or 28.58 %), 2,338,642 in 1830 (increase of 566,986 or 32.00 %), 2,873,648 in 1840 (increase of 535,006 or 22.87 %), 3,638,808 in 1850 (increase of 765,160 or 26.62 %), 4,441,830 in 1860 (increase of 803,022 or 22.06 %), and 4,880,009 in 1870 (increase of 438,179 or 9.86 %).

*Compendium of the 9th Census* pages 12 and 13.

https://www2.census.gov/library/publications/decennial/1870/compendium/1870e-02.pdf?#[2](https://www2.census.gov/library/publications/decennial/1870/compendium/1870e-02.pdf?#)

And those figures may help to indicate the possible size and scope of any possible excess mortality among black Americans during the decade of 1860 to 1870.